# How to do programmatic profiling while running a testng

Tags: java, profiling, jvmti

I'm planning to do some profiling around a set of regression test cases. My idea is to leverage AOP around the testng methods which will invoke some profiling tool api and print the profiled data at the end of the test case execution. I want to log data such as number of objects created, memory used, etc. during the test execution.

Just wondering if there's an open source profiler API which will help me in getting the data ?I take a look into JMVTI, but not sure if it can provide me the information I'm looking at. Moreover, it needs to have an agent deployed and invoked through command line.

Any pointers will be highly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at http://www.AppDynamics.com